# Define default width of Chrome DevTools window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Is there a way to give chrome a default width for the devtools window. As it is now, when I start chrome and open DevTools it takes about half the window width. Ideally I would do something like

```
$> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/"Google Chrome" 
      --devtools-width=300
```

and tell it what the width is.

To give a bit of context, I'm running Puppeteer which, in my case, opens DevTools when it starts the browser. But its too wide for me, I need to resize it everytime. Here is my configuration:

```
await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
        args: [
            '--debug-devtools',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--allow-running-insecure-content',
            '--disable-notifications',
            '--window-size=1920,1080'
        ]
    });
```

But I think this is not a puppeteer question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**puppeteer-extra**](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra) with [puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences) and specify `splitViewState`.

package.json dependencies:

```js
"puppeteer": "^1.20.0",
"puppeteer-extra": "^2.1.3",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-data-dir": "^2.1.2",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences": "^2.1.2"
```

Usage:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const ppUserPrefs = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences');

puppeteer.use(ppUserPrefs({
  userPrefs: {
    devtools: {
      preferences: {
        'InspectorView.splitViewState': JSON.stringify({
          vertical: {size: 300},
          horizontal: {size: 0},
        }),
        uiTheme: '"dark"',
      },
    },
  },
}));

puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  devtools: true,
  defaultViewport: null,
  args: [
    '--window-size=1920,1080',
  ],
});
```

P.S. to view the full list, copypaste the contents of your `Preferences` in the browser profile directory and format it with any JSON beautifier, then look up `devtools` and `preferences` inside.

Comment: Thanks it works. Do you also have a link where all this is explained?

Comment: I've found this myself by examining the prefs file. It's not explained anywhere AFAIK.

Comment: I can imagine that with this method it is also possible to choose which tab to activate. Now its always the `Elements` tab, but do you now how to enable the `Console` by default?

Comment: I see in my prefs file `'panel-selectedTab': '"console"'`

Comment: I tried to add the `'panel-selectedTab': '"console"'` at a couple of places without success. Where exactly should I place it, somewhere in the `devtools/preferences ` section?

Comment: Simply add it on a new line after uiTheme. You can look it up in your own prefs file in the browser profile directory. I see another one there `'drawer-view-selectedTab': '"console-view"'`

Comment: Please revert the edit and post a new question if needed.

Comment: Ok, that is an other question :)