# How to open puppeteer with chrome window and devtools on a separate window (detached) automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

The code below opens up puppeteer with a chrome window and devtools.
Devtools opens inside the browser.
Is there a way make devtools open in a sepearate window?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
});
```

Comment: You can just detach it manually.

Comment: How do I detach it automatically?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473581/), it should work with `currentDockState: '"undocked"'` inside `preferences` object.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474895/how-to-open-puppeteer-with-chrome-window-and-devtools-on-a-separate-window-deta#comment108746595_61474895)'s answer, here's a working example, note that `puppeteer` should import from `puppeteer-extra`

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import ppUserPrefs from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences';

puppeteer.use(ppUserPrefs({
  userPrefs: {
    devtools: {
      preferences: {
        currentDockState: '"undocked"'
      },
    },
  }
}));

puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  devtools: true
});
```