# Puppeteer: Launch Chromium with "Preserve log" enabled

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chromium

There is this handy feature in DevTools that you are able to **preserve log** (so it does not clear the content of the console nor the network tab etc. on page reloads / navigation).

[image]

At the moment my hand needs to be as fast as a lightning to click the checkbox during debugging if I don't want to miss a thing. I've already looked for corresponding chrome launch flags on [peter.sh](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) without a luck.

**Is there a way to launch chromium with this feature enabled? Can it be applied with puppeteer?**

My set up is so far:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true })
```

---

## Edit

Thanks to the comment of @wOxxOm I was able to enable it, but the solution requires three additional dependencies on the project: `puppeteer-extra`, `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` and `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-data-dir`.

**I would be interested in a solution without extra dependencies, exclusively in puppeteer.**

### `user-preferences` example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const ppUserPrefs = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')

puppeteer.use(
  ppUserPrefs({
    userPrefs: {
      devtools: {
        preferences: {
          'network_log.preserve-log': '"true"'
        }
      }
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: Try using [Define default width of Chrome DevTools window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473581) with `preserveConsoleLog: '"true"'`.

Comment: It seems to be a good approach, but can you confirm @wOxxOm that `preserveConsoleLog` is still an available option and not deprecated? It doesn't set the feature with the [user-preferences](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences) plugin and I haven't found it neither in the available pref names looking back in git for 2 years: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Devtools prefs are in different source file but it's much simpler to just read the `Preferences` file in the profile directory. Make sure you've used nested quotes as shown.

Comment: Thanks, actually it was `'network_log.preserve-log': '"true"'` that needed. I will see if there is any alternative solution with less additional dependencies (if possible I would avoid to add puppeteer-extra and two of its plugins to set this checkbox. But I admit the user-preferences is a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had some success without any extra packages:

1. Launch and close a Browser instance for the sole purpose of generating a new user data directory. Ideally you have provided your own path to it.
2. Locate the `Preferences` file (it's a JSON file), read it and write to `devtools.preferences`.
3. Relaunch a Browser (using the user data directory created in step 1)

Here's some code to get you started:

*I've used the official `puppeteer-core` package so that I can use my local installation of Chrome which is why I provided the `executablePath` option. You don't need this if you use the full `puppeteer` package.*

```js
const pp = require('puppeteer-core');
const fs = require("fs");

const run = async () => {
  const opts = { executablePath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
               , devtools: true
               , userDataDir: "/tmp/pp-udd"
               , args: ["--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"]
               };

  // open & close to create the user data directory
  let browser = await pp.launch(opts);
  await browser.close();

  // read & write Preferences
  const prefs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/tmp/pp-udd/Default/Preferences"));
  prefs.devtools.preferences['network_log.preserve-log'] = '"true"';
  fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/pp-udd/Default/Preferences", JSON.stringify(prefs));

  // relaunch with our own Preferences from our own user data directory
  browser = await pp.launch(opts);
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/q/63661366/1244884");
};

run();
```

And here's a screencast:

1. The first launch is the "launch & close" of step 1
2. Then there's the second launch that goes to this question ;) with the DevTools open and the "Preserve log" option checked right from the start.

[image]

Comment: thanks, looks promising! I need to take care of the userDataDir part, but I am sure it won't be hard to make it work :)