# How to switch from elements tab to network tab in selenium webdriver using '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have used '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs' to open developers console while running selenium automation. By default its opening in Elements tab.I want to switch to Network tab or console tab. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: You need to provide `"lastActivePanel": "network"` in devtools `preferences` object when creating the connection, here's an example for [puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473581).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 devtools:
      preferences: 
        panel-selectedTab: '"network"'
```

This worked Thanks to @wOxxOm